# Can't boot to Ubuntu 13.04 after installing

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.04, live-cd, boot-repair

I know that there is lots of people with the exact same problem, but I can't get an answer from another place (I've really been trying for hours), so here is my problem.

I got Ubuntu 13.04 on my CD and I installed it beside Windows. Something went wrong and it said

> "Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error"

I could choose where to install the bootloader and I selected /sda . But after rebooting, I went to Windows, which I didn't wanted to. I tried the boot-repair (recommended) and it said:

> Boot successfully repaired.
>
> You can now reboot your computer. Please do not forget to make your
>   BIOS boot on sdb (500GB) disk!

I rebooted and I got ubuntu, just like I wanted. But then after an hour of using, I pressed at 'Shut down'. Like 2 hours after, I came Again but saw the Windows logo another time. I tried to use the boot-repair and it said the exact same thing, but when I rebooted I just went to Windows Again.

So That's my problem. I have the link for the first boot-repair 'installation' right here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5631563/.

Does anybody have an idea of what to do? Can I activate something that will make the computer asking me for which OS I wanna use when I start up (It did after the first boot-repair)? Or can't I just make ubuntu my default?

UPDATE:
In BIOS Settings, I can choose between these:

- International CD/DVD ROM DRIVE
- USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk
- USB CD/DVD ROM Drive
- Notebook Hard Drive (Really think this is Windows)
- ! USB Floppy
- ! Network Adaptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two 500 GB hard drives. It seems like there are multiple windows systems installed on the first drive (`sda1, sda2, sda3`), and a Ubuntu system on the second drive (`sdb6`). To reach the GRUB menu, you simply need to set your BIOS to boot from the second HDD, as boot-repair told you, because GRUB is installed in the MBR of `sdb`.

Comment: I updated the first post. Which one do you think I should use? I listed them like the first post, so it starts with the International CD (...) and end with the "! Network Adaptor". But I can't reach GRUB menu.

Comment: Try booting the USB Hard Disk, is your second drive an external USB drive? Seems like there is also a 4GB flash drive, remove that for now. Do you have the Ubuntu installer on a CD?

Comment: Yes, I have Ubuntu 13.04 installer on a CD. I'm not really sure what the external is, and what anything is. Only that the Notebook Hard drive is Windows.

Comment: Try the second option in the BIOS "USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk". External means, that the device is plugged into the notebook by a USB or other connector. Is anything connected to your notebook that way?

Comment: Well, only the CD that contains the ubuntu installer.

Comment: Have you tried that boot option?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8615/discussion-between-grimpitch-and-user1994248)

Comment: The problem is that I can, when the computer starts, press F10 to set the boot order (see first post for the order), or F9 for the current options. When I press F9 is it like all the options that is available right now. And there is no "USB Diskette on Key/USB (...)"